# opencv detecting hallway edges and straight lines in realtime/still images

Tags: python, image, opencv, object-detection

I have a picture that looks like this.

I do know that in **simplecv**, you can use:

```
img = Image('hallway.jpg')
img.show()
img.edges.show()
lines = img.findLines()
lines = lines.filter(lines.length() > 50) 
lines.show()
```

I am wondering if anyone knows any library/document or can point me in any direction, that is able to detect the edges of corners, doors etc in real time or in still images **with OpenCV**?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Opencv python has implementations of Hough lines which could help. While the algo is heavy, there's a probabilistic version of it that works in realtime. You can even adjust parameters to make it faster at the cost of accuracy.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('hallway.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
minLineLength = 100
maxLineGap = 10
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[0]:
    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow("preview", img)
cv2.waitkey(0)
```

Note that you might have to adjust thresholds in canny and other parameters according to your requirements.

An alternative is to use contours. This might help https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html

Comment: hello! wow this looks a lot heavier than simplecv. I've tried googling but i couldnt really find much. Thanks for your contribution! I really appreciate it.

Comment: It's not actually heavy. It is just not hiding many implementation details and giving you more control over things. Here's the documentation from OpenCV containing a little explanation on how it works. https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html